# Android socket connect freezing

Tags: android, eclipse, sockets, networking

I am trying to implement a simple socket that sends and receives strings from a server.

The following code is freezing the application, not sure if I have done something obviously wrong?

```
public String internetRoutesRetrieve(String userName) {
    String command = null;
    String response = null;
    Socket socket = null;
    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
    DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;

    try {
        socket = new Socket("Hidden IP", HiddenPort);
        dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        command = "SEARCH <" + userName + ">";
        dataOutputStream.writeUTF(command);
        response = dataInputStream.readUTF();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        if (socket != null) {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (dataOutputStream != null) {
            try {
                dataOutputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (dataInputStream != null) {
            try {
                dataInputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return response;
}
```

Thanks

Edit: It seems the program is freezing when I am trying to save the response from the server

Comment: which thread run this?

Comment: I am not using a thread as target api is 8

Comment: not sure I'm following, this obviously run on client side, does Android user thread run this? or some other thread?

Comment: Yes client side, the main thread runs this method. The information back and fourth is small and simple so I didn't feel the need to create it on a new thread.

Answer (score 0):

see [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for proper client server communication on Android application.

you'd usualy get `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` if you don't but I'd give it a try.